# create setup project that includes .Net Framework 3.5 SP1

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-installer

I am creating a setup project. The client would like to have the setup.exe file that includes already the .Net framework 3.5 SP1.

However, when I right click setup project | properties
On the "properties page" there is a button called "Prerequistes.."

There you have 3 choices:
Vendors's website
same location as my application
download from following location.

However, the client doesn't want to download anything. So I need to package it with the setup.exe.

Is there any way to do this?

How big will the setup.exe, if it includes the .Net framework?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [full .net 3.5 sp1 installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en) is 231 Mb which is rather large to include on a disc. If you want to go down this route then [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/haarongonzalez/archive/2007/04/09/772757.aspx) should help.

If it's just for a single client in a one-off scenario you could stick all the pre-reqs on a file share somewhere on their network and use the "Download prerequisites from the following location" option.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your response. The problem is that the client could be anyone connected to the internet who wants to download our software and run on their computers. However, if they don't have the .Net framework installed it means its a big download. Our client is concerned about this.

Comment: In that case the client really has no choice. If you choose the vendors website option, it won't download the full 231Mb at once - it will download the 2-3Mb setup package and safely manage the rest of the download in the background

Answer (score 2):

http://geekrick.blogspot.com/2008/08/frustrating-net-framework-sp1-issue.html
 and
http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm#General%20Issues

are good guides.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/
(i hate this)  but i thought you should see it.
Hey its only 28meg HE HE HE  , ya and it ONLY puts on the stuff that you need.
where do they get the information from?

You see i guess after making some .net Stuff, the developer can tell the "user" hey piece of cake only 28meg.
To bad that is only for the Installer.
hey anybody else know of an updater program that takes 28MEGS ??

ok ok, but it is small cute and the client will never know LOL , hey its working for someone out there ;-)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the info. I have finished the project now. But, I wouldn't mind giving it a try, just to see if it does work 100%.