# Are there any C# to C converter tools?

Tags: c#, c

I know C# is different from .NET Framework, C# is a programming language that standard by ECMA (ECMA-334) and ISO (ISO/IEC 23270).

I don't want a converter that converts **ANY** C# source code (including .NET Framework) to C, but I want a tool that converts an ECMA standard C# source code to ANSI C source code.

Something like [java2c](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java2c/) but for ECMA C#.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The biggest problem is that you would need a C library with the same API as the .NET framework...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need this?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: No, I don't want .NET Framework library for converting.

Comment: @oded: cross-platform programming.

Comment: You can use mono

Comment: C# can be used on Linux, iOs, Mac, Windows, XBox and Android (most of the non windows provided by Mono and the different Ximian products). Do you need something outside of these?

Comment: @oded: Image that write an application with C#, convert it to ANSI C, compile for AVR :)

Comment: Have you looked at the [.NET micro framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/netmf/default.aspx)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1812805/629926

Comment: Questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, [tools are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not exactly such thing, but the Vala programming language is able to take a source code very similar to C#, and generate C codem or compile it directly.

http://live.gnome.org/Vala

Of course, the only problem are the libraries: C# has a lot of API's that you'll have to provide, or modify your source code to adapt to the Vala standard library.

If you wanted to translate this code to C because you need it compiled, there are other possibilities.

For example, ngen in the microsoft world:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.80).aspx

In the mono project, you can create a single exe file with the interpreter and the libraries. Look for mkbundle:

http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime

Mono is able to compile "ahead of time", i.e., generate the native code even before the program is going to be executed, so it will run faster.

http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime#Ahead-of-time_compilation

Comment: I found this, not sure how it would do: https://cscpp.codeplex.com/

Comment: Seems interesting, though it compiles to "managed" C++, i.e., C++ using the BCL, not ISO C++. If that fits your needs, then it is great.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what you mean. If you mean "*Is it possible to convert C# to readable and maintainable C-code?*", then sorry, the answer is **no** — C# features don't directly map to C.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Comment: If could post as comment would do it. But as see I new here so don't have that option. I want add comment it not easy make readable code when convert from C# to C. have not right do so had make answer instead. I have use tools my self for this. It compiling code but not easy maintain.