# Creating a 32 Bit DLL using C# or Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, dll, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting .NET App to x86 native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778878/converting-net-app-to-x86-native-code)

is there  a way to create a standard (not .NET Assembly type) 32Bit DLL for Windows using C# or Java?
And for WinCE ??
Thank you

Comment: It seems unlikely you'd be able to create a non-.NET assembly using a .Net language like C#, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Create a c/c++ DLL project and export some functions. That can be invoked by .net with interop.

Comment: For .NET see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778878/converting-net-app-to-x86-native-code and Java see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-exe (and the questions linked from there).

Comment: When you compile it in Java don't forget to make and export table.

Comment: Is your requirement to allow native DLL loading (i.e. `GetProcAddress`) to work, or to run without the runtime dependencies of a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

This was referenced in one of the comments, but I wanted to post it as an answer:

For C#:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1779505/490561

Basically, the idea is to use Mono and then Ahead Of Time Compilation. I think that'd do the trick.

For Java, the idea is similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2011727/490561