# Clickonce Wpf Embed .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce Wpf application which needs .Net 4.5 to run. My users are all over the country (about 60 of them) and organizing admin rights for each pc is going to be a very difficult task. Is there a way to embed .Net 4.5 into my application so I don't have to install .Net 4.5 on each user's pc ? I have already statically linked the sqlite database to remove the VC Redistributable installation.

Thx for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must be administrator to install .net framework, there is NO sane way around this.

there are some tricks like once mentioned in:

[.NET Framework install w/o admin rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567060/net-framework-install-w-o-admin-rights)

but thats generally a very bad idea.

WIN8 users will have it installed.

WIN7 will have only 3.5 maybe downgrade to .net 3.5? do you really use 4.5 features?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ClickOnce and your user doesn't have the Framework 4.5 installed the installer will check this and will automatically download the correct Framework.

To summarize you have nothing to do, ClickOnce process handle this for you.

Comment: Thx for the reply, but my users don't have administrator rights on their pc's and the installer stops when trying to install .NET 4.5. I have tested the installer on pc's that have admin rights and then it installs fine.

Comment: Did you try to run the installer by selecting "Run as Administrator"? According to forums/documentations this is not necessary. Can you create a batch to instal the framework as Admin and then run ClickOnce?

Comment: I do not have an admin account of my own for each user's pc, but I'll try to deploy with .NET 3.5 and see if that works.