# How to make portable a C# winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, deployment, portable-applications

I have developed an application in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. With

1. .Net framework 4.5
2. sql server 2012 express
3. Crystal report 13

I want to make my application portable, i meant that i should need to copy the folder of application to deploy it. Just like Tally accounting software or VLC Media player.

Please suggest me how can i do.
If this is not possible in described technology then please suggest in which plate-from it can be possible.

My application needs a DBMS to store data and a printing solution for print documents.

This question is unique as per condition that i have used 2 tools, i want to make portable my application with sql server express and crystal report. If it is not possible then please suggest portable replacement of both tools

Comment: Haider, when u compile ur app, go-to debug (or compiled) folder, copy the exe + all content to a new folder, does it run ? then try another machine...see what happens....

Comment: okk, thanx for suggestion, But i dont think so it will run on another computer that has not installed Crystal report and sql server

Comment: Haider, if your calling functions that need the app installed, then yes, you'll need the app installed, you can pull almost anything into your proj tho, if you reference it and copy the dll's etc, be aware if you copy licensed files into your app, then you know the deal....

Comment: If you are using .Net Framework, SQL Server and Crystal Report then those should be installed in that pc where you want to run it. Crystal Report Could not be run without its runtime library. Sql Server Could not be connected without database engine. So, I would like to suggest you to use light weight tools for it. for example use MS Access DB, RDLC, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can .Net Application be converted into a Portable App i.e. single .exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110704/can-net-application-be-converted-into-a-portable-app-i-e-single-exe)

Comment: can you suggest tools to replace in place of sql server express and crystal report ?